# Gitlab pipeline: How to recache node modules only when dependency changed?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am working on the performance tuning for Gitlab pipeline using `cache`.

This is a nodejs project using `npm` for the dependency management. I have put the `node_modules` folder into cache for subsequent stages with following setting:

```
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - npm install
  cache:
    key: $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    paths:
      - node_modules/
```

- Could I make the cache available for pipeline triggered next time? Or the cache is accessible in single pipeline?
- If I can access that within multiple pipeline, could I recache the node module only when we change package.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, put the cache on the global level. This will make sure, that the jobs share the same cache.

Second, you can use `cache:key:files` introduced with GitLab 12.5 to only recreate the cache when the package.json changes.

```
cache:
    key:
        files:
          - package.json
    paths:
      - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - npm install
```

Further information:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cachekeyfiles

Additional hints:

- You might want to check on `package-lock.json` instead of `package.json`.
- I recommend reading the [cache mismatch chapter in the documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/index.html#cache-mismatch) to make sure you don't run into common problems where the cache might not be restored.
- Instead of simply adding `npm install`, you can also skip this step when the `node_modules` folder was recreated from cache. Following bash addition to your npm install will only run the command, if the node_modules folder doesn't exist.

```
build:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
  script:
    - if [ ! -d "node_modules" ]; then npm install; fi
```

Comment: How would that work when using `npm ci`, by default `npm ci` will clear the `node_modules` folder and start over. Is there any way to implement efficient caching when using `npm ci`?